# How cut any integer number?

Tags: output-formatting

I have this output:

```
(323909701210368 Sqrt[3] t^(56/3))/(11 Gamma[2/3] Gamma[59/3]) + (
 23266815064996478976000 t^(71/3))/(Gamma[2/3] Gamma[74/3])
```

I want to have  numbers just with 3 digits.
For example:

```
(323 Sqrt[3] t^(56/3))/(11 Gamma[2/3] Gamma[59/3]) + (
 232 t^(71/3))/(Gamma[2/3] Gamma[74/3])
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A truly weird question! I cant imagine why you would want to do that but here goes..

```
f[i_] := FromDigits[IntegerDigits[i][[;; 3]]];
((323909701210368 Sqrt[3] t^(56/3))/(11 Gamma[2/3] Gamma[
       59/3]) + (23266815064996478976000 t^(71/3))/(Gamma[2/3] Gamma[
       74/3])) /. 
 {Rational[x_Integer /; x > 1000, y_] :> f[x]/y, x_Integer /; x > 1000 :> f[x]}
```

> (323*Sqrt[3]*t^(56/3))/(11*Gamma[2/3]*Gamma[59/3]) + (232*t^(71/3))/(Gamma[2/3]*Gamma[74/3])

Comment: maybe `x>999` instead of `x>1000`?

Comment: Many many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This goes and modifies the displayed box form. Please note that this is not meant to be used as input to other computations, just for display - so it's similar to `MatrixForm` in that sense.

```
ClearAll[ShortIntegerForm];

ShortIntegerForm[expr_] := 
 ToBoxes@expr /. 
   n_String /; 
     StringMatchQ[n, Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4, \[Infinity]}]] :> 
    Tooltip[StringJoin[StringTake[n, 3], 
      "\[InvisibleSpace]\[Ellipsis]"], ToExpression@n] // DisplayForm
```

Now you can apply this form to your expression:

```
(323909701210368 Sqrt[3] t^(56/3))/(11 Gamma[2/3] Gamma[
      59/3]) + (23266815064996478976000 t^(71/3))/(Gamma[2/3] Gamma[
      74/3]) // ShortIntegerForm
```

> [image]

As an added bonus, `Tooltip` shows the full value if you take your mouse pointer over the short form.